# read() with Keysets, ranges

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I've started playing around with the Spanner Python client (on appengine flex), but I'm hitting a few walls when trying to reuse the doc examples.
One issue I'm facing is trying to read the database:

- execute_sql() returns empty sets (even with a simple 'SELECT 1' query)

  ```
  with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
  QUERY = ('SELECT 1')
  result = snapshot.execute_sql(QUERY)
  for row in result.rows:
      print(row)
  ```
- read() returns a "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_pb'" error, whether I

  - try to build the whole keyset as a dictionary

    ```
    keyset = {'keys': ['f0_'], 
              'ranges': [{'startClosed': [], 'endClosed': [500]}], 
              'all': False}
    ```
  - passing value lists directly

    ```
    keyset = [0, 1, 2]
    ```
- and an attempt at using the Keyset() constructor tells me that spanner does not have a keyset member
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keyset'

  ```
  keys = ['f0_']
  ranges = spanner.keyset.KeyRange(start_closed=[], end_closed=[500])
  keyset = {
      'keys': keys,
      'ranges': ranges,
      'all': False}
  keyset = spanner.keyset.Keyset(keys=keys, ranges=[range])
  ```

So I'm a bit stuck, and I'm wondering whether there's something I'm doing wrong or the examples / docs need a bit of spolishing...
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: ok so I've moved a tiny bit forward:
was able to use the Keyset / Keyranges constructor, but I get the same result....

Comment: moving forward, one step at a time: I could have noticed earlier that session.read() returns a StreamedResultSet (vs. ResultSet as described in the docs). 
Adding .consume_all() does yield the expected result !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, but you can use the `KeyRange` and `Keyset` like so.  Also, `.consume_all()` is likely to be private in the future.  You should instead use `list` to get the answers that you want.

```
...
range = spanner.KeyRange(start_closed=[START], end_closed=[END])
keyset = spanner.KeySet(ranges=(closed_closed,))
rows = list(snapshot.read(self.TABLE, self.COLUMNS, keyset))
...
```